# Move physical extents inside one PV on LVM

Tags: lvm

I've got the following PV :

```
  /dev/md4   vg_raid lvm2 a--   50,93t <17,39t        0 4978957 datas 7630170 linear /dev/md4:0-4978956
  /dev/md4   vg_raid lvm2 a--   50,93t <17,39t  4978957 4456448             0 free
  /dev/md4   vg_raid lvm2 a--   50,93t <17,39t  9435405 2857369 datas 4769147 linear /dev/md4:9435405-12292773
  /dev/md4   vg_raid lvm2 a--   50,93t <17,39t 12292774  101549             0 free
  /dev/md4   vg_raid lvm2 a--   50,93t <17,39t 12394323  957483 datas 3811664 linear /dev/md4:12394323-13351805
```

TO be able to reduce the size of this LV, I wan to move the extents at the end to the beginning of the free spaces. So I've tried those combinations :

```
pvmove -i 10 /dev/md4:12394323+957483 /dev/md4:4978957
pvmove -i 10 /dev/md4:12394323+957483 /dev/md4:4978957+957483
pvmove -i 10 /dev/md4:12394323+957483 /dev/md4
```

But all returns the error `No extents available for allocation.`
Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm sorry, I misread the end of the documentation. All you need is to add the `--alloc anywhere` option....